# Android way to use Bitmaps from Camera.setPreviewCallback

Tags: android

```
camera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    private long timestamp=0;
    public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.e("CameraTest","Time Gap = "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-timestamp));
        timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();

        Bitmap mFaceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        if (mFaceBitmap!=null) FaceDetection.calculate(mFaceBitmap);

        camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
        return;
    }
});
```

I have a camera View, and in front of a simple View (where I can draw something). 
I'd like to draw on the front of View, when I can find the face of a human. 
But `mFaceBitmap` is ever and ever return null, why?

If this is a bad idea, how can I do this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set-up the camera you will need to set the preview size and the preview format. Here is some sample code to give the rough idea:

```
int previewFormat = 0;
for (int format : parameters.getSupportedPreviewFormats()) {
  if (format == FORMAT_NV21) {
    previewFormat = FORMAT_NV21;
  } else if (previewFormat == 0 && (format == FORMAT_JPEG || format == FORMAT_RGB_565)) {
    previewFormat = format;
  }
}

// TODO: Iterate on supported preview sizes and pick best one
parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);

if (previewFormat != 0) {
  parameters.setPreviewFormat(previewFormat);
} else {
  // Error on unsupported format
}
```

Now in the callback you can do something like:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  Bitmnap bitmap;
  if (previewFormat == FORMAT_NV21) {
    int[] previewPixels = new int[previewSize.width * previewSize.height];
    decodeYUV420SP(previewPixels, data, previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgbPixels, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
  } else if (previewFormat == FORMAT_JPEG || previewFormat == FORMAT_RGB_565) {
    // RGB565 and JPEG
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inDither = true;
    opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);
  }
}
```

And finally, the conversion

```
 static void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {

   final int frameSize = width * height;

   for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
     int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
       int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
       if (y < 0)
         y = 0;
       if ((i & 1) == 0) {
         v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
         u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
       }

       int y1192 = 1192 * y;
       int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
       int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
       int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

       if (r < 0)
         r = 0;
       else if (r > 262143)
         r = 262143;
       if (g < 0)
         g = 0;
       else if (g > 262143)
         g = 262143;
       if (b < 0)
         b = 0;
       else if (b > 262143)
         b = 262143;

       rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks, I do this, but with facedetector, this is very slow, and using 98% of cpu usage...so I have to use openCV, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Bitmap.decodeByteArray to convert a camera's preview output into a bitmap, unfortunately.

decodeByteArray is designed for converting JPEG/PNG/etc images into bitmaps, and it doesn't have any way of knowing what the data in the preview callback is like, because it's a simple raw array of pixel values with no identifying header.

You have to do the conversion yourself. There are many ways to do this, of various degrees of efficiency - I'll write out the simplest one here, but it's also probably the slowest.

The data byte array from the camera is encoded in some particular pixel format, which is specified by [Camera.Parameters.setPreviewFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat(int)). If you haven't called this, the default format is [NV21](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#NV21). NV21 is guaranteed to work on all Android devices; on Android versions >= 3.0, the [YV12](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YV12) format is also guaranteed to work.

Both of these are YUV formats, meaning the color is encoded as a luminance (brightness) channel and two chroma (color) channels. The functions for setting pixel values on a Bitmap (primarily setPixels) require information in the RGB color space instead, so a conversion is required.  In addition, both NV21 and YV12 subsample the chroma channels - if you have a 640x480 image, for example, there will be 640x480 pixels in the luminance channel, but only 320x240 pixels in the two chroma channels.

This means you need to create a new int[] array of the right size, and then loop over the byte[] data array, collecting up a set of Y, U, and V values, convert them to RGB, and write them to the int[] array, and then call setPixels on your destination bitmap.  The color conversion matrix you need is the JPEG YCbCr->RGB matrix, which you can find at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#JPEG_conversion), for example. You can find out about the layout of NV21 or YV12 at [fourcc](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#NV21), as one example

If you really don't want to mess with all that, you can also use the [YuvImage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html) class, albeit in a roundabout way. You can construct a YuvImage instance from the preview data, as long as you're using the NV21 format, and then save a JPEG from it into a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).  You can then get the byte[] from the stream, and decode it into a bitmap using Bitmap.decodeByteArray.  This is a completely unnecessary roundtrip to JPEG and back, so it's quite inefficient and can cause quality loss, but it only requires a few lines of code.

In the latest version of Android, you can also use Renderscript to efficiently do this conversion. You'll need to copy the data into an Allocation, and then use the [YUV to RGB script intrinsic](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.html) to do the conversion.

Finally, you can pass the data and destination bitmap into JNI code, where you can access the Bitmap directly, and write the conversion function there in C or C++. This requires a lot of scaffolding, but is very efficient.

Comment: Sorry about the URLs - I've tried all the suggested ways of encoding the URL, and they all end up broken, at least in my view of this page.